# Is it feasible to model electronic components on "electron level"? Has it been done?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrons, electronics

Is it feasible to model electronic components on "electron level"? Has it been done?

Reason to ask is that I've noticed that many practical models of electronics merely try to devise a function that models the voltage changes etc. However, since in real circuits there are some "nonlinearities" such as those heard in audio electronics, is it feasible to create models on "electron level"?

Comment: Quantum mechanical effects are accounted for in the design of modern CPUs and sensors in digital cameras.

Comment: Yes.  That's what the field of semiconductor physics is all about.

Comment: Modeling the effects of nonlinearities does not require looking at anything on "the electron level".

Comment: @endolith How can it be accurate then?

Answer (score 0):

#### solid state and ensembles

The whole field of solid state physics is an attempt to discover accurate models of how electrons behave in solids. These models don't attempt to follow the behavior of every electron; that wouldn't be very useful or feasible*. Instead, they rely on *statistical ensemble* models. Stated loosely, a statistical ensemble is the set of all possible states of a system.  For example, if you tell 12 students to sit in a classroom with 20 desks, there are 125,970 different ways for the students to take a seat (assuming we only care whether a seat is filled, not who sits there). Thus the ensemble model would have 125,970 different states, and we could talk about average values among the ensemble. The same is true of electrons in a solid. So while it is true we have very reliable models of what electrons do in solids, they don't discuss what those electrons do on an individual basis, but rather the behavior of the ensemble.

#### *why not just simulate every electron?

When you say 'model' do you mean 'simulate'? Running simulations of electrons is  possible, but not for very many at once as the number of variables you need quickly gets out of hand. To do a proper, fully quantum-mechanical simulation of 100 electrons, in the simplest scenario, would require approximately $2^{100}$ variables. That places un-achievable constraints on our current computer technology.